# If Wolverine's skeleton is completely bonded with Adamantium, why are his teeth still white?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-origins-wolverine

In "X-Men Origins Wolverine", Logan undergoes an operation to have Adamantium bonded to his skeleton.

Why doesn't the Adamantium bond to his teeth?

Comment: Because Len Wein and Co. wanted Wolverine to **cut** through stuff and not **chew** through stuff! ;)

Comment: Teeth aren't made of bone.

Comment: Bones are mainly Collagen. Teeth are mainly Dentin. And that's just the internal difference.

Answer (score 20):

Interesting point - since Wolverine is a fictional character, it could simply be because adamantium teeth are not good looking.

However according to [this article](http://sciencenordic.com/why-don%E2%80%99t-teeth-heal-themselves) It seems to be related that teeth do not have any cells to repair themselves, plus they are exposed to what we breath in and eat.

Maybe the bones that where bonded where only the ones that could repair themselves. Wolverine could heal himself quickly if not instantly, so it would stand to reason that the bones inside the body would be able to cope with the transformation, and the teeth couldn't.

Then again, it is only a theoretical answer for a fictional character.

Comment: Theoretical is perfectly alright :)

Comment: But if his teeth are not indestructible, and not self repairing. How doe she have any left?

Answer (score 13):

In humans, teeth make up part of the skeletel system but they are not classified as bones. Teeth are made up of Dentin and Enamel whereas bones are made up of Osseous tissue.

So I imagine the adamantium only bonded to the Osseous and not the Dentin or Enamel which results in adamantium bones and shiny white teeth.

Answer (score 6):

I think the most simpliest answer is that the adamantium was **injected into his body**, where it covered his bones.  In order for his teeth to be covered the injected metal would have had to ooze out of his gums into his mouth.

Answer (score 6):

**the goal of the experiment was to bond the admantium to the bones inside the body forming the skeletal framework only**

When wolverine was 'bonded' with admantium, the experiments carried out were to inject and turn the bones into admanitum so that a skeleton of this 'super-metal' will make the body highly resistant to damage. The admantium was only injected into his bodily bones, and not over his teeth and other appendages. It is the same as asking why admantium was not put over his 'nails'. The experiment was limited only to the bones making part of body skeleton. As such, wolverines claws are automatically coated with the super-metal. 
Unlike other experiments, where external claws and skin were tried to be bonded with admantium, Logan's experiment was limited to his bones.